# Update fields from superclass

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, anti-patterns

From point of various patterns is it acceptable to change fields in superclass from its descendants. For example:

```
class A {
    int barA;
}

class B extends A {
    private void testMethod() {
        barA = 4;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: subclass can access all public, protected and defult (bakage) instance variables and methods BUT it cant access the privates ones. However, it is a good practice to make all of your instance variables private and access them by Accessors and mutators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's generally not a good idea.  If I understand what you are asking, it would normally be done like

```
public class A{
     private int val;

     protected void setVal(int i){
        val = i;
     }

     public int getVal(){
        return val;
     }
}

public class B extends A{
    public void test(){
        this.setVal(4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is generally a better practice to make all your fields private, and provide public or protected setters if you want to change their value in subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine.  If the superclass doesn't want subclasses modifying values, it can make them private.

Comment: final will prevent changing values also for superclass :)

Comment: @Dedyshka True that !

Answer (score 1):

When we say class B extends A, we mean that it inherits all its (superclass' i.e. A's) variables as well. So now B has its own variable barA. Thus you can change it just like any other member variable. Further read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to do that but instead why don't you create a `getter/setter` for the same ?  It is much better to use those instead of modifying directly.

If you do not want the values modified in the subclass, make them `final`.